# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundError error while parsing text file

Tags: java, arrays, split, indexoutofboundsexception

If i execute this program which parses the text file and finds some of the codes which contains 01:09;ppp;RR:20552,40014,30141,20412,60062,20442,20362,20352,40017,40063,20402,20342,40532,40231,40512,20792,10441,40542;
as the text then i am getting arrayoutofbounderror so what is the reason

```
package FileParser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class ParsingFile {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String filename = null;
     ArrayList<String> l=new ArrayList<String>(); 
        System.out.println("Enter the file name");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            filename = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Filename entered is :" + filename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String data;
           while ((data = buf.readLine()) != null)
           {
                String[] text1 = data.split(";RR:");
                String[] text2 = text1[1].split(";");
                String[] text3 = text2[0].split(",");
                for (String e:text3) {
                 l.add(e);
                 System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       // parseJson(l);
}

/*public static void parseJson(ArrayList l)
{

}*/
}
```

Comment: On which line you get an exception?

Comment: What line is the exception on? What does logcat say? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: `text1` is probably of length **0**.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem should be there:

```
String[] text1 = data.split(";RR:");
String[] text2 = text1[1].split(";");
//                     ^                        

String[] text3 = text2[0].split(",");
```

set  validator also:

```
 if(text1.length()>1){
    String[] text2 = text1[1].split(";");
    String[] text3 = text2[0].split(",");
  }
```

Comment: Yes.. This is the only place where this exception could occur in his code.

Comment: text1[1] will be `20552,40014,30141,20412,60062,20442,20362,20352,40017,40063,20402,20342,40532,40231,40512,20792,10441,40542;`

Comment: like @MarounMaroun says, there is no other options for this Exception,

Comment: wow thank u soo much it worked,but length is not the method it must be attribute other than that the idea works :)